# Alternative to Unique(Filter)

Tags: excel, repeat

I have a dataset (single column) with repeating numbers. One number can repeat consecutively for 10 rows then switch to another number that repeats for 26 rows and may even go back to a previous number and repeat for another 30 rows. I used the cell code =UNIQUE(FILTER(L:L, L:L<>"")) but this does not capture non-unique repetition. I want to get the sequence of numbers that captures the number every time the repetition changes.

```
Dataset 
10
10
10
10
4
4
4
4
9
9
9
4
4
4


Desired 
10
4
9
4
```

Comment: One way: add a helper column that detects a change in the dat, and filter on that

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=LET(rng,A1:A14,rang2,A2:A15,FILTER(rang2,rang2<>rng))
```

[image]

or, if you do not mind the volatile function OFFSET:

```
=LET(rang2,A2:A15,rng,OFFSET(rang2,-1,0),FILTER(rang2,rang2<>rng))
```

Comment: This is picking up blank cell, how do I make sure that it does not pick up any blank cells? and can I pick up numbers that has only a minimum number of repeats?

Comment: That was not a condition in your question.  You will need to ask a new question with those  conditions and show how you tried to do it.  This answered the question posted.